# trying to reprogram the volume keys

Tags: android, keydown, android-windowmanager

I'm trying to reprogram the functionality of the Volume Up and Volume down keys. My approach uses a floating view which intercepts the key events(similar to `chat heads` app). The view flag that I'm using is: `LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL`, but unfortunately this blocks the other events. For example, if I try to use a messenger app, the keyboard doesn't appear and the backButton is blocked. This is due to the fact that my view has the focus.

Following the [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821520/how-to-detect-backbutton-home-press-from-a-service-like-messenger-chat-head-serv) doesn't work for my case. On [github](https://github.com/xxmario/ReprogramVolumeKeys) I have the complete code.

I'm struggling with the view flags part. Do you have any idea for me? Do I have to use a different approach in order to have a view which responds to key events and doesn't interfere with the rest of the apps?

```java
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

            int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
            int action = event.getAction();

            Log.d(TAG, MotionEvent.actionToString(action)
                    + ", " + KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyCode));

            if (event != null && mListener != null) {
                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    mListener.onBackButtonPressed();
                    return true;
                }

                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "volume up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }

                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "volume down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
```